# Wrong on_release on_press or widget-access from second click on

Tags: kivy

If I click the first time everything works, but from second time on, nothing happens any more during `on_press`. I'm expecting to appear "Your name is..." again. Why isn't it in my label again? And how can I get it again with the StringProperty method?

py file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class Login(BoxLayout):
    outpt = StringProperty()

    def access_widget_1(self,inpt_name):
        self.outpt = 'Your name is : ' + inpt_name

    def access_widget_2(self,inpt_pwd):
        self.ids["outputlabel"].text = 'Your password is: ' + inpt_pwd

class WidgetAccessApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WidgetAccessApp().run()
```

widgetaccess.kv:

```py
<Login>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TextInput:
            id: inpt_name

        TextInput:
            id: inpt_pwd

        Button:
            text: "Run!"
            on_press: root.access_widget_1(inpt_name.text)
            on_release: root.access_widget_2(inpt_pwd.text)

        Label:
            id: outputlabel
            text: root.outpt
```

I tried with `outpt: outpt` in my kv-file, but that leads to a NameError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

The first time when you run your code:
It will works as expected as the logic is just there.

BUT, after you invoke the function `access_widget_2(self,inpt_pwd)`, something happened:

Originally: 
`outputlabel.text = root.outpt`
It will make the binding thing happen,

After invoke: 
`outputlabel.text = "Your password is blahblahblah"`

You see?
There is no binding anymore, now `outputlabel.text` is just a plain string. Actually, if you change the text in the 2nd text input. You will notice that it does change but only for the `access_widget_2`

This is why it doesn't seem to work after 1st time, and the fix is just as simple as:

```
def access_widget_2(self,inpt_pwd):
    self.outpt = 'Your password is: ' + inpt_pwd
```

Why it works now? because you didn't break the binding this time.

Answer (score 1):

Try acces the label by property in both methods:

```py
def access_widget_1(self,inpt_name):
    self.outpt = 'Your name is : ' + inpt_name

def access_widget_2(self,inpt_pwd):
    self.outpt = 'Your password is: ' + inpt_pwd
```

Comment: Yes, that is working. But I would like to understand why the method - on kivy.com called "best practice" - is not working how I expected.